# Integrating paypal into a cakephp project

Tags: php, cakephp, header, paypal

This is probably a very simple question but having read my way through most of the paypal website and consulting a few tutorials online I'm none the wiser (well only a little bit wiser).

I'm a bit of a newb and although I've played around with php & html etc for quite a few years I've never attempted something like this. I should point out that I've made a few simple cakephp projects so I'm confortable enough with it I think, also I'm not doing this for a commercial project, it's just so I can learn ;)

What I'm trying to build is an app which requires my users to have a paypal account. With that in mind I have a signup page which collects the users paypal email and a couple of other bits of info related to my site. I then want to use the paypal authentication service https://www.x.com/community/ppx/authentication to make sure they have a paypal account.

The docs talk about sending requests and receiving responses and this is the bit I've not done before and which confuses me.

My best guess is that I have my form which my user fills in, then clicks submit. This submits to an action in my users controller which sends the request - from what I can gather that involves me doing $this->redirect(array('action' => 'https://api-3tpaypal.com/nvp')); but I'm not sure exactly how to attach the various parameters that are meant to go with that.

After that I run out of guesses. I have no idea how I receive the response or where it goes to although I know that once I manage to get a hold of it I need to check it somehow to see if it was a success before doing anything else.

I realise that this is probably something that I should really know but I've never had to do it before. Also I promise I have read LOTS on the paypal site but I'm still confused.

If there are any kind sages out there who fancy helping out a budding programmer I'd be most grateful

Thanks so much :)

Julia

Comment: I know its not the answer you want but I have to give some free advice - learn the langue(PHP), FIRST. Then go after frameworks & APIs.

Comment: Hi there, as I mentioned I have learnt php, I've just not done anything overly complex with it. All I'm asking is a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: You ever get this working?  I have a [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/) that would make this pretty simple for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Cake framework but in general this how NVP API generally work.

- Methods & parameters are sent as part of URL itself, mostly as HTTP GET request but it can be sent to server as HTTP POST as well. Incase of GET, the URL format is similar:

`http://domain.com/method_name/?param1=value1&param2=value2&param2=value3`.

- In case of HTTP POST, the parameters are not part of URL but sent separate. so URL format does contain any parameters.

For dealing with HTTP POST,  here is an example using `curl`

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://domain.com/method_name/';
$fields = array(
            'USER'=>urlencode('API_usernam'),
            'PWD'=>urlencode('API_password'),
            'SIGNATURE'=>urlencode('API_signature'),
            'VERSION'=>urlencode('version'),
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close the connection

curl_close($ch);

//print result data from server
var_dump($result);
```

For more, [Curl Library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) is pretty nice. I advice you read the documentation & take it from there.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Gaurish, this is more like what I was looking for, thank you. This should help me figure out the request part. Thanks :)